# Get youtube subtitles via tuber

Tags: r, youtube

I am trying to get the subtitles (written in blue colour) under the title of a youtube video. The do not always exists but are often used to link for example the geographic location where the video was shot.
I tried out 'tuber', but the information is not included executing the function 'get_video_details'. Neither youtubecaptions is doing the job because this is only returning the captions of the video.
Any idea how to get those subtitles with 'tuber' or a similiar package?
Thank a lot

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the code you have tried. Also, add the URL of the video you're trying to get the subtitles. Add the current and desired results - see **[ask]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

You may want to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/be66cbc2ca0816328199e2025ec51c696ea7105a) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com) by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=location&id=VIDEO_ID you will retrieve the location (the blue color text) in the JSON entry `item["location"]`.

An example of YouTube video id with such a location (`PARIS`) is [`72kRM86V-dw`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72kRM86V-dw).